# LARAVEL 8 - Tinker get null when I try to check the linked tags to each article?

Tags: php, mysql, tags, laravel-8, tinker

Larvel 8
I need some help here.. I don't know where is the error?

->>> I got "null" when I wrote in the TINKER  " $article->tags;"

### Tinker (HERS IS THE ERROR): ????????

[image]

### Creating_tags_tabels.php:

[image]

### Tags.php:

[image]

### Articles.php:

[image]

### DB table-> tablePlus
"article_tag"  :

[image]

### DB table-> tablePlus
"tags":

[image]

and this throws a error later in the next episode when i try to link tags to articles in the "Show.blade.php" file.

Answer (score 1):

First Of All The Name Convention of Laravel Should Singular Like `table = users`  then `model = User` So You Should change Articles To Article

Second in Your `Article` Model the name of the Belongs To Relation change `tags to tag` because Article Belongs to Tag Not Tags
You would use `tags` if it was HasMany Relation

Third it seems that you should eager loaded the model's relations in tinker like below

```php
$article = App\Models\Articles::with('tags')->first();
//then
$article->tags
```

Comment: this should work without selecting tags in query. i mean what is the point of having relationship if you are selecting with tag?

Comment: yes it'll work but this called eager loading [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) **Eager Loading**

Answer (score 1):

```
php artisan make:model Articles -m

php artisan make:model Tag -m

php artisan make:migration article_tags_table



  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


class ArticleTagsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('article_tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('articles_id')
                    ->constrained()
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('tags_id')
                    ->constrained()
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unique(['article_id','tag_id']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

project in gitlab and clone link
[link](https://gitlab.com/wassim.86/laravel-many-to-many-relation.git)

Answer (score 0):

try using in your articles model.

```
public function tags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'article_tag', 'article_id', 'tag_id');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it :

1- articles_tag to articles_tags

[image]

@r89human
2- In Articles.php > Tags function ( belongsToMany )

[image]

It worked for me like this ^^

@Khaled

I made it like this because I had to instead to changing all the project conventions names.

[image]

... finally it worked for now.

[image]